Shapes in Jetpack compose android
I'm trying to create a custom card in Jetpack Compose that has a specific shape. I want the card to resemble a particular shape (as shown in the image below) with rounded corners and a custom contour.
I've started with the code below, but I'm unsure how to adjust the curves and the shape to match the image exactly. Here’s the target card shape image:

How can I make a background similar to the picture?
Here is my code, I have tried but couldn't achieve similar shape.
@Composable
fun CustomCard(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    val radius = with(LocalDensity.current) { 19.dp.toPx() }
    val cornerRadiusDp = 80.dp
    val cornerRadius = with(LocalDensity.current) { cornerRadiusDp.toPx() }

    val padding = 10.dp

    // Create a custom shape
    val shape = remember {
        GenericShape { size, _ ->
            val width = size.width
            val height = size.height

            moveTo(0f, radius)
            quadraticTo(0f, 0f, radius, 0f)
            lineTo(width - cornerRadius - radius, 0f)
            quadraticTo(width - cornerRadius, 0f, width - cornerRadius, radius)

            quadraticTo(width - 1.1f*cornerRadius, 1.1f*cornerRadius, width - radius, cornerRadius)

            quadraticTo(width, cornerRadius, width, cornerRadius + radius)

            lineTo(width, height - radius)
            quadraticTo(width, height, width - radius, height)

            lineTo(radius, height)
            quadraticTo(0f, height, 0f, height - radius)

            lineTo(0f, radius)
        }
    }

    Box(modifier = modifier) {
        Card(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            shape = shape,
            colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
                containerColor = Color(0xFFBFE8FB)
            )
        ) {
            content()
        }

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(cornerRadiusDp - padding)
                .align(Alignment.TopEnd)
                .background(
                    color = Color.Blue,
                    shape = CircleShape
                )
        ){
            Text(
                text = "1",
                color = Color.White,
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
            )
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun ContextCardPreview() {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Red)){
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            CustomCard(modifier = Modifier
                .width(200.dp)
                .height(180.dp)
            ) {

                val price = buildAnnotatedString {
                    withStyle(SpanStyle(color = Color.Green)) { append("$") }
                    append("0.00")
                }

                val labelStyle = remember {
                    TextStyle(fontSize = 18.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Light)
                }

                val priceStyle = remember {
                    TextStyle(fontSize = 18.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
                }

                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Text", fontSize = 18.sp)
                    //Text(text = price, style = priceStyle)

                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(0.8f))

                    Text(text = "Text", style = labelStyle)

                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(0.5f))
                    Text(text = price, style = priceStyle)
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(0.04f))
                }
            }
        }

    }
}


Checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78921186/23490097

I used the same code, but I want it to have the same shape as in the picture. I added the differences I want in the red boxes, and that's my issue.

This is an improved version of this answer, which gives you even more control over the outline of the shape.
/**
 * cornerRadius : control the corner radius
 * gapCornerRadius : radius of the gap corner
 * gapSize : size of the gap
 * padding : padding between gap and button circle
 * concavityFactor : control the concavity of the gap
 */
@Composable
fun CustomCard(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    cornerRadius : Dp = 20.dp,
    gapCornerRadius : Dp = 30.dp,
    gapSize : Dp = 80.dp,
    padding: Dp = 10.dp,
    concavityFactor: Float = 1.05f,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    val cornerRadiusPx = with(LocalDensity.current) { cornerRadius.toPx() }

    val gapCornerRadiusPx = with(LocalDensity.current) { gapCornerRadius.toPx() }

    val gapSizePx = with(LocalDensity.current) { gapSize.toPx() }

    // Create a custom shape
    val shape = remember {
        GenericShape { size, _ ->
            val width = size.width
            val height = size.height

            moveTo(0f, cornerRadiusPx)
            quadraticTo(0f, 0f, cornerRadiusPx, 0f)

            lineTo(width - gapSizePx - gapCornerRadiusPx, 0f)
            quadraticTo(width - gapSizePx, 0f, width - gapSizePx, gapCornerRadiusPx)

            quadraticTo(width - concavityFactor*gapSizePx, concavityFactor*gapSizePx, width - gapCornerRadiusPx, gapSizePx)

            quadraticTo(width, gapSizePx, width, gapSizePx + gapCornerRadiusPx)

            lineTo(width, height - cornerRadiusPx)
            quadraticTo(width, height, width - cornerRadiusPx, height)

            lineTo(cornerRadiusPx, height)
            quadraticTo(0f, height, 0f, height - cornerRadiusPx)

            lineTo(0f, cornerRadiusPx)
        }
    }

    Box(modifier = modifier) {
        Card(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            shape = shape,
            colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
                containerColor = Color(0xFFBFE8FB)
            )
        ) {
            content()
        }

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(gapSize - padding)
                .align(Alignment.TopEnd)
                .background(
                    color = Color.Blue,
                    shape = CircleShape
                )
        ){
            Text(
                text = "1",
                color = Color.White,
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
            )
        }
    }
}

You can play with the CustomCard parameters to see the effect of each argument. This way you can use whatever values ​​you like.
Here is an image to see each parameter visually:


Excellent, thank you so much

Very good and explanatory answer with arrows and titles.

I have referred to this post and made some changes to achieve what you needed.
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.CircleShape
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.GenericShape
import androidx.compose.material3.Card
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalDensity
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

@Composable
fun CardExample(){
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        CustomCard(modifier = Modifier
            .width(200.dp)
            .height(200.dp)
        ) {

        }
    }

}

@Preview
@Composable
fun CardPreview(){
    CardExample()
}

@Composable
fun CustomCard(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    val radius = with(LocalDensity.current) { 30.dp.toPx() }

    val cornerRadiusDp = 80.dp
    val cornerRadius = with(LocalDensity.current) { cornerRadiusDp.toPx() }

    val padding = 15.dp

    // Create a custom shape
    val shape = remember {
        GenericShape { size, _ ->
            val width = size.width
            val height = size.height

            moveTo(0f, radius)
            quadraticBezierTo(0f, 0f, radius, 0f)
            lineTo(width - cornerRadius - radius, 0f)
            quadraticBezierTo(width - cornerRadius, 10f, width - cornerRadius, radius)

            quadraticBezierTo(width - 1.0f*cornerRadius, 1.0f*cornerRadius, width - radius, cornerRadius)

            quadraticBezierTo(width, cornerRadius, width, cornerRadius + radius)

            lineTo(width, height - radius)
            quadraticBezierTo(width, height, width - radius, height)

            lineTo(radius, height)
            quadraticBezierTo(0f, height, 0f, height - radius)

            lineTo(0f, radius)
        }
    }

    Box(modifier = modifier) {
        Card(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            shape = shape
        ) {
            content()
        }

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(cornerRadiusDp - padding)
                .align(Alignment.TopEnd)
                .background(
                    color = Color.White,
                    shape = CircleShape
                )
        ){
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.etherium),
                contentDescription = "",
                contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            )
        }
    }
}



Thank you so much
